# Failed on Deploying ExtGWT-Spring project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat6, gxt

I'm developing an application using UI technologies Ext-GWT version 2.x and Spring Framework. Previously I imported an existing project, and then make some changes in the interface. After I did the "Run on Server" using Eclipse Indigo, it turns out the changes that I did, is not happening. Interface remains as usual. I try to print something on the Main panel, also did not display anything on the console, while if I do print something on the back-end that using Spring Framework (still on the same eclipse project), something is printed in the console.

Is there anyone ever experienced the same problem? How is the solution to this problem?
I've tried deleting all the files in the build folder, to be "forced" to get a compilation of new classes, it did not solve the problem.

Any suggestion, clue, will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the browser cache before refreshing to see your changes.

Browsers cache .js files and sometimes your changes are not reflected right away.